# How to do geo ip blacklist with istio ingress gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm using Kubernetes service in Alibaba Cloud, kubernetes server version is **v1.14.8-aliyun.1** while istio version is **1.2.7**.

From this istio official tutorial(https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/), I learnt how to block a single ip from istio ingress gateway. I apply these **rule, instance and handler** in istio-system namespace and my public ip was blocked successfully.

Then I try to use similar concept to do geo ip blocking. First I get the country IPs list from **GeoLite2** database provided by **MaxMind**, then i parse those IPs into multiple **handler** files(3000 ip list per file as there is a resource size limit in kubernetes). Eventually let's say I want to block IP from US, I will have around 500 **handler** files generated from 25MB US-IP.txt. Now when I apply these resources into kubernetes, when I observe **Istio Mixer** log, I can see the following error:

```
Error receiving MCP response: rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (4623689 vs. 4194304)
```

I tried to set the **Istio Mixer MaxMessageSize** to 30MB, but still getting this error. Looks like this 4MB is the limit from golang grpc library.

Can anyone please give me an idea how to do geo ip blocking with istio ingress gateway? Step to reproduce this issue is included in https://github.com/heylong6551/istio-issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide commands used to debug this issue and how the config was applied into the mixer. How did you deploy Istio - configuration?

Comment: In addition please provide information of the cluster state, are all istio components health and running?

Comment: @Hanx I have included the resources, steps to reproduce this issue in https://github.com/heylong6551/istio-issue.

Comment: I also included the information of cluster state and istio components health as png in the github repo. Please be noted that the istio components health was screenshotted when the mixer log still showing the error above.

Comment: Because I'm using Alibaba Cloud Kubernetes Service, Istio is deployed using helm chart provided by Alibaba Helm Repository and its version is 1.2.7

Comment: I am not sure if it's good approach to provide all those ip's into istio directly it will impact your cluster performance. Please take a look for alibaba cloud solutions to figure out about solution at the higher level like firewall security groups access control solution and Alibaba cloud API SDK solutions.

Comment: @Hanx thanks for your suggestion, I will look into another solution to solve this. :)

Comment: It looks like you can apply ~39 rules till you get this limit, did you try with mcpMaxMsgSize `Max message size received by MCP's grpc client (default 4194304)` as per [docs](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/pilot-discovery/)

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: Why not create a dedicated micro-service for the blocking logic? Put this blacklist microservice outside your cluster. It will forward all valid traffic to your cluster.

Comment: I was trying to recreate this issue using istio 1.3.4 but unfortunately with the same results. There is no change I still got the same results `ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (4237450 vs. 4194304)` due to the default grpc message size.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda, yes, thinking to use haproxy to implement this blocking feature. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: @Hanx looks like the MaxMsgSize that we configured does not take effect right?

Comment: On my side with istio 1.3.4 without effect.

Comment: If you were able to configure those limits and it's working please share with community with your experience if it's still not working please create issue on github to make sure those istio flags works as expected.